# Are there any advantages of using separate RDBMS for reports?

Tags: open-source, sql-server, concurrency, rdbms

My production database is SQL Server 2008 R2 Express. It has limited features and I am testing it in a production environment. To better handle reporting queries in a highly concurrent environment, I want to use any open-source RDBMS with tables that will be acting as temporary tables to frequently fill recent records and delete them after use.

The only problem is that I need to keep two connections for each RDBMS, but I feel, Firebird or PostgreSQL can give me better performance of reports in a highly concurrent environment.

What are your suggestions? Is this approach used in any commercial scenario?

Comment: Are you asking about the general approach or for specific database recommendations?

Comment: Isn't this question better suited for the DBA Stack Exchange site? According to their [FAQ](http://dba.stackexchange.com/faq) it would seem on topic there.

Comment: @PersonalNexus: I guess this question involves programmers also, so not entirely suited for DBA.StackExchange.

Comment: @Oded For any specific scenarios.

Comment: I do not know about SQL Server, but MySQL supports different storage engines and you can choose a storage engine for your database geared towards more writes or more reads. MySQL also supports the powerful search server tool called Sphinx, which makes searching many times faster in mysql.

Comment: @ImranOmarBukhsh Agree. As I am using SQL Server Express, it has a 1 GB RAM limit and therefore querying complex reports is slowing performance. MySQL may be a good choice. Let me know more about Sphinx.

Comment: @ZaphodBeeblebrox Ok. Please move it to DBA.StackExchange.

Comment: @ZaphodBeeblebrox No I wanted programmer's perspective too, but none replied.

Comment: @RPK You asked an hour ago, on a Saturday! Give it a couple of days :)

Comment: @RPK : sphinx is a very powerful search server. Setting it up is pretty easy, can search millions of records in a jiffy, stores its own index. One would utalize sphinx to seach for records matching certain criteria, sphinx would return the record ids that match that criteria and these ids can be used to search an indexed keyfield in mysql. http://sphinxsearch.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Beware of the programmer's solution. We are too willing to take on the challenges brought on by the current restrictions. Why have two different databases when you can buy the recommended version of SQL Server for a production environment or just switch completely to an open source rdbms if costs are an issue?

Eventually, you may have to off-load reporting to another server or datamart, but you're not there yet just because you've pushed the boundaries of the Express version.

Comment: I want to move to Firebird or PostgreSQL, but don't know how easily support is available for PostgreSQL and Firebird on StackOverflow and other sites. Upgrading SQL Server to Enterprise Edition involves much official debate.

Answer (score 2):

The term 'reporting' is a bit loose. Some people use it to reference the result of basic queries. If this is the case, then as Jeff O says 2 different databases is not good if you need to update both databases with each transaction.

If you mean serious reporting, your options are to:

1 - Use the non-express version (as suggested by Jeff O) or

2 - Use a Data Mart type of solution (with its own database) with Star Schema and ETL jobs to periodically refresh the 2nd database. This is not as trivial as some may think, also it is not easy to maintain specially with new applications where schema changes are possible. However, this is a common way to perform reporting. It provides very fast response for queries because of the the Star Schema and batch aggregations. If you have large data, you may consider a dedicated server for this solution.

I don't know how your schema looks like or what kind of reports you are after, or how much data is there, but strive for having 1 database whenever feasible its much less troublesome.